# Error in predict(), R will not call predict.averaging() from MuMIn

Tags: r, predict, mumin

Any help greatly appreciated, thanks in advance.

I have averaged three GLMM models using the `model.avg()` function within the `MuMIn` package. I would now like to predict from this averaged model. However, when I call `predict()` R seems to think I want `predict.merMod()` and hence throws a warning message because I have asked for standard errors, which are not provided by `predict.merMod()`. Instead I am wanting to call `predict.averaging()` which is the appropriate call for a model of class `averaging` and will provide standard errors for model predictions. If I try to force R to use `predict.averaging()` by specifying `MuMIn::predict()` or `MuMIn::predict.averaging()` I get an error saying that the function is not exported from `MuMIn`.

Any help to resolve this would be greatly appreciated? I want to predict from an averaged model, of class `averaging`, and want to obtain estimates as well as standard errors.

Reproducable example below.

```
# Load packages
> library(MuMIn); library(lme4)

# Create test data set
> test <- rbind(mtcars, mtcars)
> test <- rbind(mtcars, test)

# Create test models
> t1 <- glmer(am ~  hp + (1 | carb), data = test, family = binomial)
> t2 <- glmer(am ~  hp + vs + (1 | carb), data = test, family = binomial)

# Create model list and average models
> list <- list(t1, t2)
> p1 <- model.avg(list)

# Create new data set for predictions
> nd <- mtcars[1:2,]
> nd <- select(nd, hp, vs)

# Model predictions demonstrating errors and warnings
> predict(p1, backtransform = TRUE, newdata = nd, re.form = NA, se.fit = TRUE)
    Mazda RX4 Mazda RX4 Wag 
    0.8938837     0.8938837 
Warning messages:
1: In predict.merMod(object = new("glmerMod", resp = new("glmResp",  :
  unused arguments ignored
2: In predict.merMod(object = new("glmerMod", resp = new("glmResp",  :
  unused arguments ignored

> MuMIn::predict(p1, backtransform = TRUE, newdata = nd, re.form = NA, se.fit = TRUE)
Error: 'predict' is not an exported object from 'namespace:MuMIn'

> predict.averaging(p1, backtransform = TRUE, newdata = nd, re.form = NA, se.fit = TRUE)
Error in predict.averaging(p1, backtransform = TRUE, newdata = nd, re.form = NA,  : 
  could not find function "predict.averaging"

> MuMIn::predict.averaging(p1, backtransform = TRUE, newdata = nd, re.form = NA, se.fit = TRUE)
Error: 'predict.averaging' is not an exported object from 'namespace:MuMIn'

> MuMIn:::predict.averaging(p1, backtransform = TRUE, newdata = nd, re.form = NA, se.fit = TRUE)
    Mazda RX4 Mazda RX4 Wag 
    0.8938837     0.8938837 
Warning messages:
1: In predict.merMod(object = new("glmerMod", resp = new("glmResp",  :
  unused arguments ignored
2: In predict.merMod(object = new("glmerMod", resp = new("glmResp",  :
  unused arguments ignored
```

Comment: Try `MuMIn:::predict.averaging()`

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. I get the same error message: ```In predict.merMod(object = new("glmerMod", resp = new("glmResp",  :unused arguments ignored```

Comment: This looks like the _warning_  from above though rather than the _error_. Anyway, we need you to provide commented, minimal, self-contained, reproducible code, consider: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example/5963610#5963610

Comment: Thanks again. I have now edited to include a reproducible example.

Comment: Well done! However, there simply seems to be no option for computing standard errors, see my answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `glmmTMB` instead of `lmer`- the syntax is identical and it yields similar results while allowing for `se.fit` in `predict`, and is often more efficient.

Internal `predict` replacement for `"merMod"`, which calculated `se.fit`, has been removed as of MuMIn 1.43.9 since R complains about packages overwriting registered methods.

Answer (score 1):

It's the `se.fit=TRUE` option that's causing the warnings. There appears to be no option for computing standard errors for `glmerMod`. `MuMIn:::predict.averaging` has an option `se.fit=`, but it internally applies `lme4:::predict.merMod` which has not (that's the reason why we receive the warnings), and which help page states:

> `?lme4:::predict.merMod`
>   There is no option for computing standard errors of predictions
>   because it is difficult to define an efficient method that
>   incorporates uncertainty in the variance parameters; we recommend
>   `bootMer` for this task.

In other words, you could try to bootstrap prediction errors using `lme4::bootMer`. The authors of package [`merTools`](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/merTools/index.html) discussed [alternatives](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/merTools/vignettes/Using_predictInterval.html) to calculate prediction intervals (their function `merTools::predictInterval` won't work for averaged models like yours, though).

Probably it isn't that hard to write a bootstrap method from scratch, see e.g. [this post on *Cross Validated*](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/226565/bootstrap-prediction-interval). Unfortunately I'm too unfamiliar with that model to help you further, and things are getting too statistical for *Stack Overflow*, but you could ask a related question on *Cross Validated* on how to calculate/bootstrap prediction standard errors for averaged generalized linear mixed-effects models.

Comment: Thanks jay.sf, I really appreciate this. I also suspected that it was the ```se.fit``` component that was driving the warnings but was confused as ```MuMIn:::predict.averaging``` suggests that it provides a CI. I suspect something may have changed recently in the underlying code. This relates to a script that I have opened after not touching for about two months and it worked last time I ran it, weird. I only opened script up again to edit a figure I had previously created, which I now can't re-create.